# Split PDF's into multiple parts

Tags: files

Is it possible to allow pdf uploads to be split automatically by drupal?

Example1: If I upload a PDF with 4 pages. Drupal will split it into pdf(page1), pdf(page2),etc...

Example2: I upload a pdf that is 10mbs, It can logically split the files into a limit. So if the limit was 5mbs. It would split the file into 2 even parts...

Comment: Drupal wouldn't be able to do this itself. You'd have to use something like GhostScript http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal can't out of the box. Doesn't mean YOU couldnt in PHP :) (i think)

I've written PDFs on-the-fly using Ruby and mucked with it in PHP soooo ....

Using Fields in Drupal you could supply an File Upload widget for PDFs.

Then write a module to process the file on upload,

Using PHP's built in PDFs functions like:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-get-pdi-value.php

simply get the numbers of pages, and then retrieve each page's content and make a new simple 1 page PDF out of it. Then save the file and FID to another Field of files with unlimited values for any number of pages .... It sounds doable for most PDFs (not necessarily crappy built non-standard PDFs) -- but definately some work .... :)

Answer (score 0):

Re: per page, you might look at the [PDF to ImageField](http://drupal.org/project/pdf_to_imagefield) module.  It can create image snapshots of each page.

Comment: It would work but the client requires the file to be a pdf as these are legal documents getting sent to courts.